# unable to connect to hidden WIFI

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

I have Xubuntu 16.04 and when i try to use the **connect to hidden WIFI network** I can choose the network i prepared before but the button connect is always dimmed

the user i use is member in these groups

> $ groups
>
> root adm dialout fax cdrom floppy tape sudo audio dip video plugdev
> netdev lpadmin scanner sambashare vboxusers

so how i can solve this issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1542733

The workaround is to use a terminal like

```
nmcli c up id "SSID"
```

where you replace `SSID` by the name of your hidden Wifi.

Answer (score -3):

Practically, using a hidden SSID is not helpful anymore.  It was really helpful back in the days of Windows XP or earlier when hidden networks were not showing anywhere unless one used specific third party software for revealing them.

Now, as you can see, it's just one more click and they're there.  It's better to unhide your network SSID, maximize your protection settings using **WPA2/AES-256** exclusively and using a 20 or 32 character strong passphrase.

This way, you will use the maximum protection current wireless encryption technology can offer.

Comment: thanks for the advise but i need to be able to use this feature

Comment: others may encouter this issue for networks they have no control or choice about